# Python IndentationError when I try to create a loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have this section of Python code which works correctly

```
   import mss
   import mss.tools
   import datetime
   import time

    with mss.mss() as sct:
    monitor = sct.monitors[1]
    timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    sct.compression_level = -1
    output = "d:/screen/work/" + (timestr) + ".png".format(**monitor)
    sct_img = sct.grab(monitor)
    mss.tools.to_png(sct_img.rgb, sct_img.size, output=output)
    print(output)
```

I would add a no end cycle/loop with a 10 second delay between each loop, so I added a *while* in this way

```
    import mss
    import mss.tools
    import datetime
    import time 

        while count < 100000000:

        with mss.mss() as sct:
        monitor = sct.monitors[1]
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        sct.compression_level = -1
        output = "d:/screen/work/" + (timestr) + ".png".format(**monitor)
        sct_img = sct.grab(monitor)
        mss.tools.to_png(sct_img.rgb, sct_img.size, output=output)
        print(output)    

        time.sleep(10)
        count += 1
```

but it returns this

*IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level*

How to add a loop in my code ?

Comment: You need indentation after `with mss.mss() as sct:` as well, so if this code is working you didn't post the actual code, and we can only guess (although a very good one) what is the problem.

Comment: there is no other code , I usually code with php and truly I do not understand this python logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there should be always an indent after the `:`

```
import mss
import mss.tools
import datetime
import time 

while count < 100000000:

    with mss.mss() as sct:
        monitor = sct.monitors[1]
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        sct.compression_level = -1
        output = "d:/screen/work/" + (timestr) + ".png".format(**monitor)
        sct_img = sct.grab(monitor)
        mss.tools.to_png(sct_img.rgb, sct_img.size, output=output)
        print(output)    

        time.sleep(10)
        count += 1
```

Comment: is it not exactly my code above , I do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

In Python there's no curly braces and code block start/end carried by indents, so you should indent `with`. It says that `with` is doing inside `while`.

```
while count < 100000000:
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        monitor = sct.monitors[1]
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        sct.compression_level = -1
        output = "d:/screen/work/" + (timestr) + ".png".format(**monitor)
        sct_img = sct.grab(monitor)
        mss.tools.to_png(sct_img.rgb, sct_img.size, output=output)
        print(output)    

    time.sleep(10)
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several functions which require the indentation of the code that follows: `for`, `while`, `if`, `with`.  The compiler (in python) needs the indentation to know with lines of code are triggered by which conditional statements.  For instance, you want

```
    time.sleep(10)
    count += 1
```

to always execute during each iteration of `while`.  Therefore the compiler needs to see:

```
while count < 100000000:
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        monitor = sct.monitors[1]
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        sct.compression_level = -1
        output = "d:/screen/work/" + (timestr) + ".png".format(**monitor)
        sct_img = sct.grab(monitor)
        mss.tools.to_png(sct_img.rgb, sct_img.size, output=output)
        print(output)    

    time.sleep(10)
    count += 1
```

Otherwise those two lines are only executed during the `with` portion of the loop.

Comment: is it not exactly what my code is doing ? Shame on me , I do not undestand .

Comment: The code you posted as working *cannot work* because some lines are only indented 1 space instead of the required 4 spaces.

Comment: I understood , so spaces are important and mandatory ! (Very different from php)